# Error CS1061 "double[]" no contiene una definición para "Select" ¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Quiero usar una libreria matemática llamada **MathNet** para hacer una regresión lineal simple. [El ejemplo de la pagina official](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Regression.html#Simple-Regression-Fit-to-a-Line) es el siguiente.

```
   using System;
   using MathNet.Numerics.Statistics;
   using MathNet.Numerics;
   using System.Collections.Generic;


    private void RegresionLineal()
    {
        double[] xdata = new double[] { 10, 20, 30 };
        double[] ydata = new double[] { 15, 20, 25 };

        Tuple<double, double> p = Fit.Line(xdata, ydata);
        double a = p.Item1; // == 10; intercept
        double b = p.Item2; // == 0.5; slope
      
        Tuple<double, double> t = Fit.Line(xdata, ydata);

        double r2 = GoodnessOfFit.RSquared(xdata.Select(x => a + b * x), ydata); // == 1.0    

    }
```

El caso es que me está dando el error CS1061 para el método **Select()** y no sé como solucionarlo.

Me gustará saber si falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado tal y como dice el error. ¿O tal vez el problem es otro?

El método **RSquared()** está definido de la siguiente forma por si sirvie de ayuda.

```
RSquared(IEnumerable<double> modelledValues, IEnumerable< double > observedValues)
```

Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, el problema se solucionó incluyendo la librería LINQ

```
using System.Linq;
```

Lo supe gracias a esta [fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230729/where-is-the-fold-linq-extension-method)